# JSON support of Metrics

Tags: json, cassandra, dropwizard, cassandra-3.0, codahale-metrics

I want to fetch various metrics of Cassandra in JSON format. I read about [Metrics JSON support](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/json/). However, there weren't many details given. I don't know what exactly it does and if it can be used for fetching Cassandra's Metrics in JSON format, how exactly can I do that? In a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606698/using-metricsservlet-to-fetch-metrics-in-cassandra), I've asked about achieving the similar objective using [MetricsServlet](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/servlets/), but it seems to me metrics-json might be similar and that is why I want to know exactly why/how it should be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MetricsServlet to fetch metrics in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606698/using-metricsservlet-to-fetch-metrics-in-cassandra)

Comment: I've added some details about the question.

Comment: Per other question, you should try mx4j to expose the jmx metrics with http, a lot less work. Or just use JMX

Comment: Thanks. I want to know about metrics-json as well.